# Use Gitlab-installed Helm from CLI. Could not find tiller

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I've created a kubernetes cluster on AWS using Kops, and I've correctly configured the cluster on Gitlab.

I've installed Helm Tiller and Ingress from Gitlab's panel, but I now wish to uninstall the Ingress chart.

I'm not sure how to uninstall the ingress chart. What I'm tring now is configuring my Helm CLI to delete the ingress release, but I'm not getting the Helm CLI correctly configured. The Tiller stuff is being deployed at the `gitlab-managed-apps`, so I'm trying the following command:

```
$ helm init --tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps --service-account tiller --upgrade
HELM_HOME has been configured at C:\Users\danie\.helm.

Tiller (the Helm server-side component) has been upgraded to the current version.
Happy Helming!
```

But then when I'm trying to issue the `helm ls` command I'm getting the following error:

```
$ helm ls
Error: could not find tiller
```

But the service account exists on the namespace:

```
$ kubectl get serviceAccounts -n gitlab-managed-apps
NAME                    SECRETS   AGE
default                 1         23h
ingress-nginx-ingress   1         23h
tiller                  1         23h
```

Any ideas how to get the CLI correctly configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have installed tiller to a namespace that is not the default namespace.
As per default the Helm CLI will assume tiller is installed in default and that this is the namespace you want to "get in touch with"

this can be fixed by using the `tiller-namespace` flag as for your example that'd be

`helm list --tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps`

Comment: When issuing that command I'm getting the following:


`$ tiller list --tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps
[main] 2019/04/05 13:10:41 Starting Tiller v2.13.1 (tls=false)
[main] 2019/04/05 13:10:41 GRPC listening on :44134
[main] 2019/04/05 13:10:41 Probes listening on :44135
[main] 2019/04/05 13:10:41 Storage driver is ConfigMap
[main] 2019/04/05 13:10:41 Max history per release is 0`

But it doesn't end, and in a parallel terminal still says `Error: could not find tiller`

Comment: my bad, fixed the error.
it's supposed to be `helm list` instead of `tiller list`

Comment: Thanks you Rick, that solved part of the problem. Now the CLI seems to connect to the namespace, but it gets stuck and throws the following error without ant other message: `Error: context deadline exceeded`

Comment: sorry for the delay here.
That does look like something is wrong with the chart/values that you want to deploy. but that's a bit of guessing without seeing said files

Answer (score 0):

Try using Helm version 3 onward. Helm versions 1 and 2 are actually composed of two pieces – the Helm CLI, and Tiller, the Helm server-side component. It is important to note that Helm 3 removes the Tiller component, and thus is more secure